# Excluding file with profiles in Eclipse - Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to exclude some files from a Maven war build by using profiles, and just cannot figure out to get that done.

I have created two profiles in pom.xml, created an eclipse run configuration for each, and can invoke them separately.  But the resultant builds both have all the files in the eclipse project, no matter what I try.

I have simplified it to A and B, profile A is the 'default' profile.

```
    <profile>
        <id>profile-a</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>builda</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>cloud</artifactId>
                    <version>11.0.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <classifier>profile-a</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

And profile B is the one where I want to remove some files, and have tried all sorts of ways, and have reduced it to not including anything, and all the possible exclude methods are shown also.

```
    <profile>
        <id>profile-B</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>buildb</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>cloud</artifactId>
                    <version>11.0.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <classifier>cloud-service</classifier>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.txt</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <packagingExcludes>**/*.txt</packagingExcludes>                     
                        <warSourceExcludes>**/*.txt</warSourceExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

But both builda.war and buildb.war are identical - I compared the war files with Beyond Compare, and the only difference is the timestamp in the Manifest. I also tried removing a .jar file just to see if it was something about .txt files, but no difference at all.

So I'm thinking that the build information is coming from my eclipse project not from pom.xml.  Or I completely missing something - I am still a maven newbie, so that is entirely possible.

But how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I feel that I should point out that there seem to be multiple problems with the POM you've provided. I think you should take some time to read through the [Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), and related documentation.

Based on what you provided I think you're trying to add a classifier to your artifact based on the profile that was active during the build. I preserved this functionality and corrected the other aspects of the POM as best I could, but I made a few assumptions.

Here is the modified POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>web.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>exampleWar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-a</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                          <classifier>profile-a</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                      </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-b</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                          <classifier>profile-b</classifier>
                          <packagingExcludes>%regex[.*\.txt]</packagingExcludes>
                          <warSourceExcludes>%regex[.*\.txt]</warSourceExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                      </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which changes made it work, I think a misconception about what the artifact ID should be on the profiles was the big one. I did have a <build> section for the overall build.  And it seems that the <packingExcludes> is the necessary one, <warSourceExcludes> did not do anything.